# InAppPurchase Testing Error [Error while retrieving from server [DF-RPC-01]

Tags: android, android-inapp-purchase

I have a Android Application Which has inAppPurchase for subscription from the Android developer document its mentioned to use reserved id `android.test.purchased` i have give this as my product id but when i am trying to run i am always getting  the below error as mention in the screen shot,I have not published it yet in the playstore.

**Question 2:** I have also another application i have uploaded in google developer console and uploaded as beta release and i am able to see the  purchase option but it asking my card details and doing real transaction is there any way to do sand box testing like ios.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer 1:The reason for that i was testing on licence test user account `it should test actually with login of your google developer account on your mobile device.`After login with developer account on device i was successfully did the testing.

Answer 2: Yes we can do sandbox testing like IOS but in case of android we have to provide our real card details and while doing transaction it will also deduct money and again it will refunded with in 15 min.

Answer (score 2):

For subscriptions, this error will appear if you are testing subscription purchases with the test IDs. A note in the [Testing In-App Billing](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#billing-testing-static) documentation states to test subscriptions with the actual subscription SKU instead of the test ids.

From Google Doc:

> Note: If you're testing subscription purchases, you must use the product ID of an actual subscription, not a reserved product ID.